# Error: TOO MANY REDIRECTS when trying to access "/network/" on a multisite WP installation

Tags: php, wordpress, server

When trying to access the Network on a multisite installation I get the error that there are too many redirects. I want to point out that I can access the Wp admin on Site level , this error only appears when I try switching to the network wp admin.

This WP installation is a copy from a different domain and server and I am assuming thats why the multisite isnt working as expected. I have changed all DB entries and followed solutions found here on stackoverflow in regards of .htaccess and wp-config. None of these helped me solve the problem.

this is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

this is the relevant part of my current wp-config:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);    
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. This is really frustrating!

Comment: What are errors in Apache log file?

Comment: I will add that every time I try accessing the network I get the following url change: /wp-signup.php?new=thedomainname

Answer (score 0):

Here are the places I changed assuming that the multisite domain name is `multisite.example.com` and one of the subdomain sites domain is `example.com`.

### wp-config.php

`define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'multisite.example.com');`

### Database

`update wp_blogs set domain="multisite.example.com" where blog_id = 1;`

`update wp_sites set domain="example.com" where id = 1;`

`update wp_options set option_value="http://multisite.example.com" where option_id in (1,2);`

This Stack Overflow post helped: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/319355